# Structures in C as function return value

Tags: c, struct

i would like to use **strucs in plain C** to manage Data on a microcontroller. I read **a lot** of online tutorials, but could not find the solution to my problem. The **µC always runs into HardFault**.

This is the struct definition in the header file:

```
typedef struct{
  uint8_t laenge;
  uint8_t rfu;
  uint16_t nsi;
  uint8_t epc_data[24];
  uint16_t crc16;
}epc_memory;
```

this is the function prototype :

```
epc_memory decodeACK(uint32_t rxBuffer[]);
```

The function :

```
epc_memory decodeACK(uint32_t rxBuffer[])
{
counter=0;
epc_memory mem;
//Anfang finden
while(rxBuffer[counter] > ERROR_) counter++;
makeString(rxBuffer,counter);
startEnding();
counter = decoder();
if(counter > 100){

        for (counter=0; counter<4; counter++)
        {
            mem.laenge = (mem.laenge << 1) | decoded[counter];
        }

        for (counter=4;counter<6; counter++)
        {
            mem.rfu = (mem.rfu << 1) | decoded[counter];
        }

        for (counter=6;counter<15; counter++)
        {
            mem.nsi = (mem.nsi << 1) | decoded[counter];
        }

        for(counter=15;counter<(15+mem.laenge);counter++)
        {
            mem.epc_data[(counter-15)/4] = (mem.epc_data[(counter-15/4)] << 1) | decoded[counter];
        }

        for(counter=(15+mem.laenge);counter<(31+mem.laenge);counter++)
        {
            mem.crc16 = (mem.crc16 << 1) | decoded[counter];
        }


    }

return mem;

 }
```

And this is how it is called in the main :

```
epc_memory tmp = decodeACK(&rxBuffer);
```

Can you spot any errors ?

Thanks

**edit:**
just for reference...
THIS function works just fine :

```
uint16_t decodeRN16(uint32_t rxBuffer[])
{
counter=0;
uint16_t rn16 = 0;
//Anfang finden
while(rxBuffer[counter] > ERROR_) counter++;
makeString(rxBuffer,counter);
startEnding();
counter = decoder();
if(counter > 16){

    for (counter=0; counter<16; counter++)
    {
        rn16 = (rn16 << 1) | decoded[counter];
    }

}

return rn16;

}
```

Comment: can you show us the `main` ? `decodeACK(&rxBuffer);` looks suspicous, I'd like to see the type of `rxBuffer`

Comment: its uint32_t rxBuffer[1024]; There is a similar function to decode other received data, which works perfect. I would suspect that the problem is related to the struct handling...

Comment: Also: What is `decoded`?

Comment: Take your compiler's warning serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do not blindly cast them away.

Comment: Any risk this steps outside the array? That `while` loop isn't bounds-checked and could run amok if the input data isn't matching what you expect. Looks very scary and definitely something I'd refactor immediately.

Comment: At which point exactly is the hardware fault?

Comment: Yet another "why does my program crash if I don't initialize the variables" question. Enable your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The code as shown misses to initialise `mem` before reading it's members' values. This might very well cause undefined behaviour. One outcome then could be a "hard fault".

To fix this replace

```
epc_memory mem;
```

by

```
epc_memory mem = {0};
```

This latter statement intialises all `mem`'s members to `0`.

---

As [*Jean-François Fabre*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre) deleted [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42859379/694576) I want additionally point out that

```
epc_memory decodeACK(uint32_t rxBuffer[])
```

if called

```
decodeACK(&rxBuffer);
```

is called wrongly.

Assuming the array's defintion to be

```
  uint32_t rxBuffer[1024];
```

call the function

```
  decodeACK(rxBuffer);
```

**Background**

```
 epc_memory decodeACK(uint32_t rxBuffer[])
```

is the same as

```
 epc_memory decodeACK(uint32_t * rxBuffer)
```

and passing an array to a function makes it decay to the address of its 1st element. Here this will be `uint32_t*`.

Passing `&rxBuffer` would evaluate to pass a pointer to an array of 1024 `uint32_t`, which would be a `uint32_t(3)[1024]`, which clearly is not what `decodeACK()` expects.

The reason it still might seem to work sometimes, is that the address of an array in fact is the same address as the address of it's 1st element.

Still passing the array's address here is passing the wrong type, is invoking the infamous Undefined Behaviour, is unreliable code, is wrong code, which the compiler clearly should have pointed you to by issuing a related warning.